# jQuery: slideUp expands element before animation

Tags: jquery

Firefox: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/Pbz3Z/)

I'm not sure if this is just my setup, but in Firefox, there seems to be a little jump in height before the animation begins.

JavaScript:

```
window.run = function(){
var $alert = $('.alert').clone();                                    // Store for another run
var maxSize = 0;

$('#start-size').html($('.alert').height());                         // Default start size

$('.alert').slideUp({
  duration:1500,
  step: function(){ 
    var _height=$(this).height();
    if (_height>maxSize) {
      maxSize = _height;
      $('#max-size').html(maxSize);
    }
  },
  complete: function(){
    $(this).remove();
    setTimeout(function(){$('.container').append($alert);},1000);   // Reset for another run
  }
});
```

};

HTML:

```
<button onClick="run()">Slide Up</button>  
<div class="container">
  <div class="content alert">
    Alert! Hide
  </div>
</div>
<div>Start Size: <span id="start-size"></span></div>
<div>Max Size: <span id="max-size"></span></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { border:1px solid black; margin:20px; padding: 5px; }
.content { border:1px solid #900; height:20px; padding:5px; }
.alert { background: #c99; color: #900; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try animating the height property as opposed to using the `slideUp()` method.

Comment: That would seem to be treating the symptom, instead of curing the problem.  I'm chaining this after a `fadeOut` (now a `fadeTo`), so using the available callback with slideUp is useful.  Setting the max-height in my other answer is also only treating the symptom, which I'd prefer, since using `slideUp` is more self-documenting than animating the height.

Comment: Not necessarily, there a lot of circumstances where you'd want to animate a specific property vs. using available methods--cases where you may not be able to control the content in the container (additional margins or markup that changes the container's height or other properties). So, animating one-specific property allows you to control the end result, and **not** have to code around issues introduced by a pre-fab method. You may find this useful: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slidedown-animation-jump-revisited/

Comment: I see what you're saying about just using animate.  What I'm trying to determine is if there is an issue with the `slideUp`, which should be patched.  Another alternative I found was to add `$(this).css({'padding-bottom':0,'padding-top':0,'line-height':$(this).height()+'px'});` to the `slideUp`'s step function.  The video showed that this was an issue with padding, but I also noticed that you have to also adjust the line-height, though that gives it a squish effect.

Comment: Alternatively, your way (to animate) would look something like: `$('.alert').parent().css('overflow','hidden').end().animate({height:0,'padding-top':0,'padding-bottom':0,'border-width':0});` Still having to remove the vertical padding and border, and making sure it stays hidden afterwards by applying the overflow to its container.  That all seems a lot more work then my `max-height` solution.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to show both examples: http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/Pbz3Z/2/  (you'll have to comment the slide and uncomment the animate one because I didn't set it up to show both)

Comment: You're better off adding a CSS class that handles that for you, e.g. `$('.alert').parent().addClass('some_css_reset_class').animate(...);` you can then call `removeClass('some_css_reset_class');` when your animation is complete or when you reverse the animation.

Comment: Still more work than max-height, but I was showing that just animate doesn't work... there's still a jump that needs to be accounted for

Answer (score 0):

It seems if you set the max height before the animation, it will fix it.

```
var $alert = $('.alert');
$alert.css('max-height',$alert.height()).slideUp({...});
```

However, I have yet to find why this is happening.